# Prevent two or more jobs get executed at the same time in Quartz Scheduler

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Just as title, I have several jobs that set trigger time at the same time but I don't want them to be executed all at once. Because I afraid that it may cause overheat problem to my system. Is there any way we can config a trigger so that its executing time may be vary between a defined offset?

For example: 
Schedule 2 jobs to be executed at 12PM: Job1 and Job2
At 12 PM: Job1 is executed.
At 12:01 PM: Job2 is executed.

Answer (score -1):

you  check this  , I hope you can find something useful to sopve your problem 
https://www.mkyong.com/java/example-to-run-multiple-jobs-in-quartz/